# Android Hard coding bluetooth MAC address

Tags: android, bluetooth

I already know the MAC address of the remote bluetooth device (say 0C:60:76:E6:C3:41).

My question is how to write a program to search and connect to only this device for which I have the MAC address.

Until now I am successful in enabling and getting paired devices list.

I tried the below code but it is giving true even if the MAC address is wrong

```
boolean BT2 =BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress("0C:60:76:E6:C3:41");
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Boolean.toString(BT2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

if(BT2==true){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connecting to"+bDevice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`checkBluetoothAddress(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#checkBluetoothAddress(java.lang.String)) clearly explains why that code isn't working- that method only checks that the given Bluetooth address is a valid address, not if a device with that address is in range.

Assuming you are following the same approach for getting a list of Bluetooth devices as described in [the Bluetooth documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#FindingDevices), then you should end up with a `List<BluetoothDevice>`. Once you have that, you can iterate through the list and call [`getAddress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getAddress()) on each `BluetoothDevice`, and compare that to the one you are looking for.